# Adding default configurations for many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, ansi-sql

MySQL here. I have the following `users` table:

```
describe users;
+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                            | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id                          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_status_id                   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| profile_id                       | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would know like to add a simple RBAC model where:

- Users can have 0+ Roles
- Roles have 0+ Permissions

My proposed table structure:

```
[roles] table
---
role_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
role_name : VARCHAR(50)

[permissions] table
---
permission_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
permission_name : VARCHAR(50)

[roles_x_permissions] many:many table
---
roles_x_permissions_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
role_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY to [roles] table
permission_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY to [permissions] table

[users_x_roles] many:many table
---
users_x_roles_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY to [users] table
role_id : BIGINT UNSIGNED FOREIGN KEY to [roles] table
```

And the actual Roles & Permissions the app will support (at least initially):

```
INSERT INTO permissions (
  permission_name
) VALUES (
  'CanDoSomeBasicStuff'
);

INSERT INTO roles (
  role_name
) VALUES (
  'BasicUser'
);

INSERT INTO roles_x_permissions (
  role_id,
  permission_id
) VALUES (
  1,    // BasicUser
  1     // CanDoSomeBasicStuff
);

INSERT INTO users_x_roles (
  user_id,
  role_id
) VALUES (
  ???
);
```

Where I'm struggling is this: by default, all existing users will have the `BasicUser` role. I need an elegant way to assign all my existing users to this `BasicUser` role in a single command, but I can't figure what the SQL command needs to look like:

```
INSERT INTO users_x_roles uxr (
  user_id,
  role_id
) VALUES (
  ???,   # How to do this for each user record in the users table?
  ???    # How to fetch the correct role_id for the BasicUser role?
)
```

**Any ideas what this SQL command might look like?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT ... VALUES` syntax inserts a single record. You need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, like this:

```
INSERT INTO users_x_roles (
  user_id,
  role_id
)
 SELECT 
  user_id, 
  (SELECT MAX(role_id) FROM roles where role_name='BasicUser')
 FROM users;
```

Or, if you do not like the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO users_x_roles (
  user_id,
  role_id
)
 SELECT 
  u.user_id, 
  r.role_id 
 FROM users u CROSS JOIN roles r where r.role_name='BasicUser';
```

Update: the typo was in the INSERT statement. I have copied your code and used the syntax like: `INSERT INTO users_x_roles uxr`, which is not valid: you can't use aliases in the `Insert Into` clause.

Now it all works fine. Check the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2438b/1)

Comment: Actually @cha both your SQL statements produce syntax errors. I do prefer the 2nd option (using the cross join) however I'm getting an `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax` error. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is causing the error. Your error is not descriptive enough. Can you make a sqlfiddle for your schema so that we can try it out?

Comment: Sure thing! [Here you go!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/436566/1) -- thanks again so much!!! **Minor edit: in reality my `users` table is called `accounts` (all users have an *account*).**

Answer (score 0):

> How to do this for each user record in the users table?

Write a query that pick exactly one user, for example:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE name = 'John'
```

---

> How to fetch the correct role_id for the BasicUser role?

Write a query that pick exactly one desired role, for example:

```
SELECT role_id FROM roles WHERE role_name='BasicUser'
```

---

In the end put these two queries into INSERT statement in this way (using brackets) :

```
INSERT INTO users_x_roles uxr (
  user_id,
  role_id
) VALUES (
  ( SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE name = 'John' ) ,
  ( SELECT role_id FROM roles WHERE role_name='BasicUser' )
)
```